# parentNode is null or undefined in draggable resizeable custom overlay with image. GMaps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have made a resizeable custom overlay with an image and it works, you can see it here,
[debug](http://wifigator.com/dash/debug2.php).  In the upper right hand corner and lower left corner there are some red corner icons that you can drag and resize the image and overlay.   The problem is that when you make the image smaller, it leaves behind remnants of the lager scale images.

I then added a function to remove the overlay before drawing the new one, straight out of the example, overlay.onRemove();  It worked, but as soon as you un click the marker it gives the error "parentnode:  object is null or undefined", you can see it here [debug2](http://wifigator.com/dash/debug.php)

If you view the source on them, the drag listener in on line 173 and calls the overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map, 'yes'); on line 194.

The function is on line 71. and looks for ifDrag and then deletes the previous overlay, I am baffled as to why it works but as soon as you un click the marker it throws the error and breaks the script.

It would be awesome if someone could provide me with a fix or workaround to the error. This is a very nice feature to have and am too close to give up. Thanks.

Comment: Your `debug2` pretty much works for me in Firefox. I don't get an error and the shape resizes pretty well. The upper right red corner bar gets moved off of the shape and the image pops outside of the 2 red corner bars if I drag very small, but those two issues just feel like you need to refine your code. What browser are you using when you get the exception?

Comment: Yes,it looks like it works but you will notice that the red corner marker does not drop into place against the image, that's where the error occurs. I'm using ie9 with it set to display script errors, that and F12 for the console. In my real map there is a dragEnd listener that re positions the marker and that breaks on the error. If That error would just go away I am good to go.

Comment: I do see the error when I use Chrome: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null [http://wifigator.com/dash/debug.php:144]`. Can you post your code?

Comment: Nevermind - the code is right in the page. It looks like the `USGSOverlay.div_` member is `null` in the `onRemove` function. I will look a bit deeper for you -

Comment: Thank you very much, that's where it is and the image has an absolute path so you can run it in your browser I have firebug open and if I do a short drag the first error is "this.div is null", as soon as I release the click it pops up with a second error the same as the first error. (since there is only one overlay it can also be overlay.div_). I don't understand how this.div_ can be null and it still clears the previous overlay.

Comment: Ok. I have some stuff I have to get done at work :) But I will check back later and see if there has been any activity here on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came to the conclusion that too many events were fired and killed the script, 'dragend' was the solution (Not perfect but works), works in all browsers and have set opacity at 50% to get the perfect alignment to the location. Appreciate your help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in the `draw` function:

```
var div;
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  // Size and position the overlay. We use a southwest and northeast
  // position of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
  // We need to retrieve the projection from this overlay to do this.
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
  // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
  // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
  // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
  var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());
  // Size the image's DIV to fit the indicated dimensions.
  div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
  div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
  div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
  div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
}
```

Don't you want to remove the external declaration of `var div` and make the references within the `draw` function reference `this.div`? I believe that is your problem.

Shouldn't the last lines of `draw` be implemented like this:

```
//Remove this line:
//div = this.div_;
this.div_.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
this.div_.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
this.div_.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
this.div_.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
```

You also have similar code in the `add` function. I suggest that you make the code in `add` similar - just work directly with `this.div_`; it looks like you might be getting a reference mixed around.

Comment: Thank you Sean Micky, I think I have some progress, it turns out that drag fires extra events and someone said to try position_changed instead of drag, it woks in ie and chrome (unless you drag outside of the window). It doesn't work at all in fireFox though. I have been working on this for two days and am seeing some light.

Comment: I have it uploaded here http://wifigator.com/dash/debug3.php, aparently fireFox doesn't like the position_changed. ARRRGH.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, still no go. I came across this [Issue](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/7ba4ae0af9515b27/96acec5ca91f4371) which recommended 'position_changed' because drag fired to many events, this did fix the issue in ie and chrome but totally broke in opera and firefox. Drag re-sizes in all browsers but crashes them all on mouse release, I suspect from the additional end events being fired.

Comment: We came to the conclusion that too many events were fired and killed the script, dragend was the solution (Not perfect but works), works in all browsers and have set opacity at 50% to get the perfect alignment to the location. Appreciate your help. Cheers.